# Apple App store app upload issues, rejected due to copyright issues

Tags: app-store, appstore-approval

I uploaded my app to app store which is contains the online TV streaming - I having the copyrights to stream the url.But the app store stills rejects my app.Please give the guidelines to solve this issue

> **Apps may not use protected third party material such as trademarks,
>   copyrights, patents or violate 3rd party terms of use. Authorization
>   to use such material must be provided upon request**
>
> We found that your app includes features for streaming TV channels,
>   the content of which may be copyrighted. The use of materials
>   copyrighted by a third party requires documented evidence of your
>   right to use such content in your application.
>
> Accordingly, please provide documentary evidence that you have the
>   rights to use this content to ensure compliance with the iOS Developer
>   Program License Agreement. A letter or link to documentation is
>   sufficient. For future app submissions, please include clarification
>   on your authorization in the Review Notes section of your app
>   metadata. Once Legal has reviewed your documentation and confirms its
>   validity, we will proceed with your app review. Be aware that while
>   your iTunes Connect Application State is displayed as Rejected, it is
>   not necessary to upload a new binary if you only need to address
>   issues in your metadata.
>
> Please remember that pursuant to your agreement with Apple, you
>   represent and warrant that your application does not infringe the
>   rights of another party, and that you are responsible for any
>   liability to Apple because of a claim that your application infringes
>   another party's rights.

Comment: What documentation did you provide to Apple?

Comment: @GrahamSavage right now i m not providing any document to Apple.I am just gave notes in resolution center

Comment: You must add documentation about permission. That the reason you select if your app have 3rd party access in your app before submit it.

Comment: @Kalai how did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

When there is matter of using third party material into application, Apple review team always make sure that it should be properly proofed. By not doing so it may take into legal issues in future.

So in all its better for the developer it self to make it proofed for the material before using it.

Better solution is if you are using the material for which you have copyrights on it Then you should provide a legal documentation copy. Or if you are using any third party material than you should have get permissions from the original owner. In that case you can get the acceptance from the original author of the material.

Hope this helps to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

When you get rejected from Apple, it's not the end of the line. You can reply to them with pertinent information to make your case valid.

Assuming you got an e-mail from them, it should contain a link near the following text: *To view or reply to the message, go to Resolution Center in App Store Connect*.

Click on that link or go to your App Store Connect > My Apps > , then Activity > Resolution Center. You should be able to select the reason you got rejected and fill out the **Reply** box. Note that there is also an **Attach File** link, include your agreement with the copyright holder, *preferably in PDF format with proper signatures*.

**Edit:** I just wanted to add that I've gotten 2 apps rejected and eventually published on the App Store. One had to go through several iterations before finally getting approved, the point is: Don't give up and do what is being requested - there's a reason Apple does all that vetting.